# Modal closes after opening

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a a picture in my localhost website. I want to show the full size of it by using a modal. It is working well, the picture is shown, but the problem is the after clicking the show modal, it automatically closes after maybe 2 seconds. Why is that?

Comment: Without seeing your code, how are we supposed to know?

Comment: Something is closing it. Look for `setTimeout ()` and kin. This really is just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem pop up before. Are you including bootstrap.js *and* bootstrap-modal.js? If so, remove the include for bootstrap-modal.js. See if that helps :)